# foreach in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I try to loop over foreach in my Registration Controller as the following

```
      $subjectStartID  = Input::get('substID');

      $subjectStart = SubjectStart::find($subjectStartID);

    //To get division_ids by the relationships using SubjectStartID
       $divisionIDs =$subjectStart->teachersubject->subject->divisions ;

    // loop over $divisionIDs to get div_ids 
    foreach ($divisionID as $div) 
        {
          $div->id ;  
        }

       return var_dump($div->id);
```

OR

```
      return var_dump([$div->id]);
```

The isuue that the result of the loop get the last id only ,
  for example
  if the div_ids (1,2) the result is (2)

i need foreach to get the div_ids to use it in the following joinQuery

```
 $check = Registration::join('student', 'student.id' ,'=' , 'registration.student_id')
                      ->join('division', 'division.id' ,'=' , 'student.division_id')
                      ->where('student.id' , $registerID->student_id)
                      ->whereIn('student.division_id',[$div->id])->get();
```

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry but what are you doing inside `foreach`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say about laravel, but from a `php` standpoint, you should use a container array to store all the ids returned in the foreach loop.

imho, so your code should look like the following...

```
 $subjectStartID  = Input::get('substID');

  $subjectStart = SubjectStart::find($subjectStartID);

//To get division_ids by the relationships using SubjectStartID
   $divisionIDs =$subjectStart->teachersubject->subject->divisions ;



$studivs = array();
// loop over $divisionIDs to get div_ids 
foreach ($divisionID as $div) 
    {
     $studivs[] = $div->id ;  
    }
```

So now the variable `$studivs` has all the ids that you need.

Comment: Awesome , thanks 9kSoft for help now the foreach working well